# HTML/CSS adjust parent div's height/width automatically according to children content

Tags: html, css

I want to make this:
[stacked cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9aA.png)

the html would look like so:

```
<div class="container>
  <div class="top-card>
   <div class="card-content">
     ...
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am having trouble styling this so that the height of the entire card adjusts automatically according to the content inside the top card. Thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, the bottom card should always be the same size as the top card. But the bottom card will have no content. Just for styling

Answer (score -1):

you can use a combination of box-shadow and `display: inline-block` to accomplish what you are trying to do. I have updated the answer. Here is the code:

```css
.grandparent {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.shadow {
  margin-left: -7px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  background: pink;
  z-index: -100;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.empty {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="parent shadow">
    <div class="child empty"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what about the border for the box shadow?

Comment: please accept my answer and upvote it if it helped you.Thanks